# Zwiebach String Theory, Quick Calculation 21.19

Tags: homework-and-exercises, approximations, volume

In "A First Course in String Theory" 2nd ed. by Barton Zwiebach, on page 489 there is a problem to be solved. It seems like a simple plug and chug but I can't make it work out. Equation (21.93) on page 488 gives the formula for the volume of a $J - 1$ sphere. It has a typo in it and should read
$$\text{vol}(S^{J - 1}) = \frac{2\pi^{J/2}}{\Gamma(J/2)}.\tag{21.93}$$
The problem asks you to use the approximation
$$\Gamma(x) \sim x^{x - 1}\sqrt{2\pi x}e^{-x}(1 + \mathcal{O}(1/x))$$
in order to show that
$$\text{vol}(S^{J - 1}) \simeq \left(\frac{2\pi e}{J}\right)^{J/2}, J \to \infty$$
By plugging in, I get
$$\text{vol}(S^{J - 1}) \simeq \left(\frac{2\pi e}{J}\right)^{J/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/J}(1 + \mathcal{O}(2/J))}$$
Of course, the extra $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the denominator is no issue, but the extra factor of $\sqrt{J}$ is. Does anyone see what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is that $\lim_{J\rightarrow \infty} J+k=J$ for any constant $k$, so
\begin{equation}
\lim_{J\rightarrow\infty} J^{-J+1/2} = \lim_{J\rightarrow\infty} J^{-J}
\end{equation}
It's maybe more obvious if you take the log of both sides:
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{J\rightarrow\infty} \log J^{-J+1/2} &=& \lim_{J\rightarrow\infty}\left[-J \log J + \frac{1}{2} \log J \right] \\
&=& - \lim_{J\rightarrow\infty} J \log J
\end{eqnarray}
Often it's useful to take logs when using Stirling's approximation.

If you apply this logic to your expression, you find
\begin{equation}
{\rm vol}\left(S_{J-1}\right) \approx \left(\frac{2\pi e}{J}\right)^{J/2}
\end{equation}
for large $J$. In other words, the "constant power" term $\sim (J/\pi)^{1/2}$ doesn't matter at large $J$.